# Too much RAM Usage in Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, handler, ram

in my application i am calling an activity, in it a new Handler is started. Later the activty gets restarted again as Long you are using the application. Is it possible that this Handler is causing the explosive RAM usage up to 450 MB because it will never be closed?

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int[] i = {0};
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("pointsCopy", pointsCopy.toString());
            appear(pointsCopy.get(i[0]));
            i[0]++;
            if (i[0] < pointsCopy.size()) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for Answering

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak. To diagnose it, you might want to learn how to use this tool : http://www.eclipse.org/mat/
Using OQL to find your leaking activity and option "path to GC roots", you'll have your answer right there. This tool is for Eclipse, Android Studio should have it's own flavor of it.
For android, remember that hprof file needs to be converted using /path-to-sdk/platform-tools/hprof-conv.exe